# How to make delay for loader on beforeSend() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm posting the form data using jquery ajax. The loading is running beforeSend() function but i wan to make it delay for some seconds and submit the data

```
$.ajax({

              type : 'POST',
              url  : 'ajax_process_register.php',
              data : data,
              beforeSend: function()
              {
                  //show loader untill getting the response from the ajax.



                  $('.loader').show();
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    th.submit();
                    }, 3000);
              },
              // after getting success response.
              success :  function(data)
              {
```

The loader is not delaying for my time. it instantly get fired to success

Answer (score 1):

Do a `setTimeout` on the ajax post. `setTimeout(ajaxFn, msDelay)`.

EXAMPLE:

```
function ajaxFn() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_process_register.php',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loader').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.loader').hide();
                th.submit();
            }, 3000);
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}

// One ms second is 1000
const delayInMs = 3000;

setTimeout(ajaxFn, delayInMs);
```

Comment: How to do that bro ?

Comment: I'm new to jquery, can you help me with example ?

Comment: Edited a example for ya =D